# Python loop over dataframe

Tags: python, dataframe, loops

I have a dataframe consisting of ticker prices.   It is 1 row per TICKER, DATE, PRICE, for a year.  So, 365 rows per ticker.   The structure is somewhat like this:

```
    TICKER  PRICE_DATE  OPEN_PRICE
0      IBM    20201113      115.19
1      IBM    20201112      115.63
2      IBM    20201111      118.12
3      IBM    20201110      116.69
4      IBM    20201109      117.88
.
.
.
#      AAPL   20201113      115.19
#      AAPL   20201112      115.63
#      AAPL   20201111      118.12
#      AAPL   20201110      116.69
#      AAPL   20201109      117.88
```

What I need to do is:  for each ticker, loop through the first 3 days, and compare the OPEN price with the previous day.   Basically something like:      IF day1 < day2 < day3 THEN.........

So, I need 3 rows of IBM, next iteration I need 3 rows of AAPL, next iteration.........

Any easy way to do this?    Or, maybe I am supposed to convert this to a different format, so I can access AAPL, price element 1, price element 2, price element 3, etc?

Comment: what is the expected output?

Comment: I want to be table to go through the dataframe (or maybe I need to convert to a diction or list??)   And take the first 3 elements for each ticker.   So like, AAPL[0].price, AAPL[1].price, AAPL[2].price.     Then same for next one.    So, rather than having to go through each ticker, 365 times and taking the first 3 rows, can I somehow convert it to a different structure and just access elements I need?

Comment: like `df.groupby('TICKER').first(3).groupby('TICKER')`?

Comment: I must be missing something:    d = df.groupby('TICKER').first(3).groupby('TICKER')   I get this error:    <pandas.core.groupby.generic.DataFrameGroupBy object at 0x7f0511a0a4e0>

Comment: this is a groupby object. It allows to apply functions and filters to groups, as, eg it was done here to take three first values. After the second groupby, however, it is not clear what result you want to get, which brings us back to my first question

Comment: Tried something else:   x = df.set_index('TICKER')[['PRICE_DATE','OPEN_PRICE']].T.to_dict().     Got this:   {'AAPL': {'PRICE_DATE': 20190621.0, 'OPEN_PRICE': 49.7}}.      DataFrame columns are not unique, some columns will be omitted..        So it is close, But each row, which is a different day for the ticker with its own price information, will become a element key/value pair.     So, I can access something like:   AAPL[0].OPEN_PRICE   or  AAPL[3].LOW_PRICE.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/224604/discussion-between-landon-statis-and-marat).

Answer (score 0):

data.csv:

```
TICKER  PRICE_DATE  OPEN_PRICE
IBM    20201113      115.19
IBM    20201112      115.63
IBM    20201111      118.12
IBM    20201110      116.69
IBM    20201109      117.88
AAPL   20201113      115.19
AAPL   20201112      115.63
AAPL   20201111      118.12
AAPL   20201110      116.69
AAPL   20201109      117.88
INTC   20201113      115.19
INTC   20201112      115.63
INTC   20201111      118.12
INTC   20201110      116.69
INTC   20201109      117.88
```

Code:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df = pd.read_csv('data.csv', delimiter='\s+')
print(df, '\n')

arr_t = np.dtype([('TICKER','S4')]) 
arr_t = df['TICKER'].unique()

df = df.set_index('TICKER')
print(df)
rows_per_ticker = df.loc[arr_t[0]].PRICE_DATE.count()

r = 0
while r < rows_per_ticker:
    for i in range(0,len(arr_t)):
        print(df.loc[arr_t[i]].iloc[r:r+3, :])
    r+=3
```

Output:

```
   TICKER  PRICE_DATE  OPEN_PRICE
0     IBM    20201113      115.19
1     IBM    20201112      115.63
2     IBM    20201111      118.12
3     IBM    20201110      116.69
4     IBM    20201109      117.88
5    AAPL    20201113      115.19
6    AAPL    20201112      115.63
7    AAPL    20201111      118.12
8    AAPL    20201110      116.69
9    AAPL    20201109      117.88
10   INTC    20201113      115.19
11   INTC    20201112      115.63
12   INTC    20201111      118.12
13   INTC    20201110      116.69
14   INTC    20201109      117.88

        PRICE_DATE  OPEN_PRICE
TICKER
IBM       20201113      115.19
IBM       20201112      115.63
IBM       20201111      118.12
IBM       20201110      116.69
IBM       20201109      117.88
AAPL      20201113      115.19
AAPL      20201112      115.63
AAPL      20201111      118.12
AAPL      20201110      116.69
AAPL      20201109      117.88
INTC      20201113      115.19
INTC      20201112      115.63
INTC      20201111      118.12
INTC      20201110      116.69
INTC      20201109      117.88
        PRICE_DATE  OPEN_PRICE
TICKER
IBM       20201113      115.19
IBM       20201112      115.63
IBM       20201111      118.12
        PRICE_DATE  OPEN_PRICE
TICKER
AAPL      20201113      115.19
AAPL      20201112      115.63
AAPL      20201111      118.12
        PRICE_DATE  OPEN_PRICE
TICKER
INTC      20201113      115.19
INTC      20201112      115.63
INTC      20201111      118.12
        PRICE_DATE  OPEN_PRICE
TICKER
IBM       20201110      116.69
IBM       20201109      117.88
        PRICE_DATE  OPEN_PRICE
TICKER
AAPL      20201110      116.69
AAPL      20201109      117.88
        PRICE_DATE  OPEN_PRICE
TICKER
INTC      20201110      116.69
INTC      20201109      117.88
```